# Two thread using same object but modifying seprate property of the object

Tags: java, multithreading

I have class as mentioned below:

```
 public class Test {
     public Test1 a;
     public Test2 b;
 }
```

Now I have 2 threads.

Thread 1 modifies "Test1" and thread 2 modifies "Test2"

Can there be a possibility of data corruption i.e. while thread 1 was modifying "Test1" class, but inbetween thread 2 came in and started modifying "Test2" and thus the changes were lost or data was corrupted/incomplete update ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are thinking so?

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario you describe there can not be any data corruption as the two scopes of modification are disjoint.  A problem will occur only if one thread attempts to access data that the other thread is in the process of modifying.  Modifying `Test1` does not affect `Test` or `Test2`.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple: when **more than one thread** writes to **shared** data; then there is potential for data corruption. When one threads **writes**, and others **read**, then the is the chance that the readers see inconsistent data.

In your example, this seems not to be the case.

Or the other way round: if **any** of the modifications to field `a` in any way affect field `b`; then you got a problem.

But beyond that: it is bad style to have **public** fields that are worked on by external components. When `a` needs to be updated; then that should happen through a method call on your `Test` object.

And beyond that: don't forget about the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)! The things that make up "one" class are closely related. Therefore it sounds also strange to have those two completely independent things within the same class ...

Comment: _"when more than one thread writes to shared data"_ -- actually it's when one thread _modifies_ data that is being read by another thread.

Comment: I think my statement is correct; but was missing something. Changing that right now.

Comment: thank you ghostCat. I have indeed used private fields and used getters & setters. The above code was just for example. Thank you for your answer.  Class Test1 & Test2 are seprate and modification of any one does not affecet the other one.